# Image::Magick on Strawberry Perl 5.12

Tags: perl, imagemagick

I am trying to install `Image::Magick` on [Strawberry Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Perl) 5.12 on Windows XP, but it doesn't find the [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) modules when it generates the makefile. The make also throws lots of compiler errors.

I did exactly what is written in the readme of [Image::Magic](http://search.cpan.org/~jcristy/PerlMagick-6.89-1/Magick.pm):

```
Installation - Win32 Strawberry perl

    On Win32 Strawberry Perl the preferred way of installing PerlMagick is the
    following:

    1) Download and install ImageMagick Windows binaries from
    http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows

    2) You HAVE TO choose dynamic (DLL) ImageMagick binaries.  Note: it is not
    possible to mix 32/64bit binaries of Perl and ImageMagick

    3) During installation select that you want to install ImageMagick's
    development files (libraries+headers)

    4) You NEED TO have ImageMagick's directory in your PATH.  Note: we are
    checking the presence of convert.exe or identify.exe tools

    5) You might need Visual C++ Redistributable Package installed on your
    system. See instructions on ImageMagick's Binary Release webpage.

    6) If you have all prerequisites 1)...5) you can simply install
    ImageMagick by running: cpan -i Image::Magick
```

And I am getting this:

```
################################### WARNING! ###################################
# It seems that you are trying to install Perl::Magick on a MS Windows box with
# perl + gcc compiler (e.g. Strawberry Perl), however we cannot find ImageMagick
# binaries installed on your system.
#
# Please check the following prerequisites:
#
# 1) You need to have installed ImageMagick Windows binaries from
#    http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php#windows
#
# 2) We only support dynamic (DLL) ImageMagick binaries
#    note: it is not possible to mix 32/64-bit binaries of perl and ImageMagick
#
# 3) During installation select that you want to install ImageMagick's
#    development files (libraries+headers)
#
# 4) You also need to have ImageMagick's directory in your PATH
#    note: we are checking the presence of convert.exe and/or identify.exe tools
#
# 5) You might need Visual C++ Redistributable Package installed on your system
#    see instructions on ImageMagick's Binary Release webpage
#
# We are gonna continue, but chances for successful build are very low!
################################################################################
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lMagickCore
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lmoldname
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lkernel32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -luser32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lgdi32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lwinspool
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lcomdlg32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -ladvapi32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lshell32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lole32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -loleaut32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lnetapi32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -luuid
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lws2_32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lmpr
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lwinmm
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lversion
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lodbc32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lodbccp32
Note (probably harmless): No library found for -lcomctl32
Writing Makefile for Image::Magick
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
```

But the ImageMagick binaries are installed and in the path variable.

How do I to get this to run?

Comment: These missing libraries look very much like the *Visual C++ Redistributable Package* mentioned in step 5. Win32 experts, please confirm.

Comment: The Visual C++ Redistributable Packages are installed on my system.

Comment: If you run "convert.exe" from command line, does it fail?

Comment: No, it works. Image Magick is in the path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution!

The problem is, that the `Makefile.pl` looks for the binaries in the wrong directories.

1. Get the latest ImageMagick package. [click](http://imagemagick.com/script/download.php)
2. Unzip it and navigate into the `PerlMagick` folder
3. open `Makefile.pl` in an editor.
4. Take a look at the first foreach block:

`foreach my $line (split '\n', $conf) {`

```
if ($line =~ /^Path:\s+(.*)/) {
  my ($vol,$dir,$file) = splitpath($1);
  next unless $dir;
  my $dirpath = catpath( $vol, $dir);
  my (@l,@b,@i) = ( (),(),() );

  # try to detect 'lib' dir
  push @l, catfile($dirpath,'..','lib');
  push @l, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','lib');
  push @l, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','..','lib');
  foreach (@l) { push @libdir, $_ if (-d $_) };

  # try to detect 'bin' dir
  push @b, catfile($dirpath,'..');
  push @b, catfile($dirpath,'..','bin');
  push @b, catfile($dirpath,'..','..');
  push @b, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','bin');
  push @b, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','..');
  push @b, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','..','bin');
  foreach (@b) { push @bindir, $_ if (-e "$_/convert.exe" || -e "$_/identify.exe") };

  # try to detect 'include' dir
  push @i, catfile($dirpath,'..','include');
  push @i, catfile($dirpath,'..','include','ImageMagick');
  push @i, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','include');
  push @i, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','include','ImageMagick');
  push @i, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','..','include');
  push @i, catfile($dirpath,'..','..','..','include','ImageMagick');
  foreach (@i) { push @incdir, $_ if (-e "$_/magick/MagickCore.h") };
}
```

}

The script gets the location of the IM installation from the %PATH% and looks for the bin, lib and include folders. It looks everywhere except at its actual location.

So you just need to add these:

```
# try to detect 'lib' dir
push @l, catfile($dirpath,'lib');
...
# try to detect 'bin' dir
push @b, catfile($dirpath);
...
# try to detect 'include' dir
push @i, catfile($dirpath,'include');
...
```

After that you can execute `perl Makefile.pl` and it will correctly generate the makefile. Then just say `dmake` and `dmake install` and you will be fine.

I hope that helps somebody sometime.

Comment: Wow man! You're my hero! This so worked for me, I was so frustrated there wasn't anything else to try out.. it worked for me and I could install it. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having some problem now with performing the dmake test. Maybe you can help me out. Here's the thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462775/test-failure-in-dmake-test-with-module-perlmagickimagemagick. I would really appreciate it

Comment: @Demnogonis, your corrections are now integrated in `PerlMagick-6.89\Makefile.PL`, but, in my case, on Windows 10, I'm getting `fatal error: magick/MagickCore.h: No such file or directory`...

Answer (score 1):

You also may try a less painful method - the Perl package manager, that comes with Strawberry Perl.

Start with "ppm" command, then type "install Image-Magick". 30 seconds and you're done.

Comment: Strawberry Perl comes with it's own ppm, and it works even better.
I've recently migrated from ActivePerl since they wanted more and more money to use their perl version. I've been with them from times when there were no alternative for perl for windows, except maniacs who were compiling everything from source with visual studio :)
But now they got too greedy, and I found this wonderful alternative.
It lacks only GUI debugger, but ActivePerl PDK works with Strawberry perl just fine.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. In principle it seems to work. Unfortunately Image-Magick is not available for the latest Strawberry version, so sometimes it will still be necessary to use CPAN.pm instead.

Comment: Doesn't ppm do the same thing as cpan? Download the package from the repo and execute the buggy makefile.pl? I've never used ActivePerl and therefore no knowledge about how ppm internally works.

Comment: Nope, ppm installs precompiled binaries. No need for compiler and no waiting, it happens in couple of seconds - if there is precompiled module version available.

Comment: This appeared to work for my `Windows 10, version 1709` with `ImageMagick 7.0.7-28 Q16 (64-bit) > Install development headers and libraries for C and C++`, but then discovered can't `Read` in jpegs...