# Test failure in dmake test with module PerlMagick(Image::Magick)

Tags: perl, testing, module, installation, strawberry-perl

I was first having problem passing past Makefile.pl installing the perlMagick module(otherwise known as Image::Magick).

It said I didn't had the required binaries installed, but a person here in SO pointed out that it was a problem with the Makefile, it didn't look for the binaries on their location. After fixing that, I had no problem with the Makefile other than
"Gonna create 'libMagickCore.a' from 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\CORE_RL_magick_.dll'"
After that, doing the dmake(I'm using Strawberry Perl for the 64-bit) with no issues, I try to perform the dmake test, which gives me this output:
http://www.textswell.com/read,4233986902330

After every line it pops an error window stating that perl.exe has stopped working.

I would appreciate any help with this, I have been stuck here for like 3 days

Comment: Those tests indicate Perl is crashing, probably because the perlMagick module build is broken. The test output won't help diagnose, but the build output will. Run `dmake clean` and then show us the output of `dmake`. In fact, not every distribution cleans completely so I'd suggest blowing the directory away and unpacking a fresh copy.

Comment: Are you using the 64-bit ImageMagick binaries, too? I tried to reproduce your error on my `Win7 64-bit` system with `Strawberry Perl 5.14` and the IM binaries from the `ImageMagick-6.8.0-4-Q16-windows-x64-dll.exe` installer from their page. It worked just fine.

Comment: @Schwern Ok, thank you very much I'll run dmake clean and unpack making a fresh copy

Comment: @Demnogonis I tried with both 64 and 32 bit binaries. They both give me trouble. I have Strawberrry Perl 5.16 on Win7 64-bit, and I have installed the exactly same binary as you (ImageMagick-6.8.0-4-Q16-windows-x64-dll.exe)

Comment: @Schewrn After making `dmake clean` and deleting the directory I unpacked the .zip file again, perform the Makefile.pl which besides the normal success output, it displayed `Gonna create 'libMagickCore.a' from 'C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.8.0-Q16\CORE_RL_magick_.dll`. After that, I did the dmake clean again, just to be sure, and performed the dmake. Here's the output: http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=NrEsZ

Comment: @Sismetic I got the same output when generating the makefile. But I noticed that two tests (read.t,write.t) fail when I test these things. But the module can still be installed. Do you have different test output?

Comment: well, I never tried to installed it because it failed the dmake test(well, actually only once and it didn't install it). I'll try it now. Ok, performing the dmake test, it fails ALL tests(telling me perl.exe has stopped working), I continued anyways doing `dmake install`, it "installed it", but when I ran `perl -MImage::Magick`, it stopped perl... also, as I use that module on some code, executing the code also stops perl.exe, so I don't think it's installed or at least, not correctly

Comment: @Sismetic I don't see anything obviously abnormal in your build code. A few things I would try is to use a version of ImageMagick matching the PerlMagick version (6.7.7 is the latest on CPAN). Also, [PerlMagick has special instructions for Windows and Strawberry Perl](https://metacpan.org/source/JCRISTY/PerlMagick-6.77/README.txt). Did you follow them? Note that your Perl and your ImageMagick have to both be either 32 or 64 bit, that could be your problem.

Comment: @Schwern I already tried that, and I couldn't get the matching versions.... Your link is very much appreciated, I hadn't seen it, I did follow all the instructions on Strawberry Perl, but not the previous ones... I'll do them and tell you what happens. Thank you very much, oh, and yeah, perl and imageMagick bot are with corresponding bits(I've tried ImageMagick with both 32 and 64-bit)

Comment: Ok, I tried it. I did everything it said. I got confused on the libraries part(lines 34 to 41 on the README.txt), but as I understood it I added JPEG.dll, TIFF.dll,etc.. to the PATH environment variable(the JPEG,etc... libraries I found on `C:\strawberry64\perl\vendor\lib\auto\Imager\File\` not on the Image Magick installation. It still gives me the errors on dmake test and perl.exe stops working whenever I use code that uses Image::Magick

Comment: @Sismetic Running out of ideas. ImageMagick has their own instructions for PerlMagick and it appears it comes bundled with their distribution.  Try that rather than the CPAN distribution?  http://www.imagemagick.org/script/perl-magick.php

Comment: Oh, I already tried that(installing from ImageMagick -http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php- rather than the CPAN distribution). It came with a lot of other stuff, but it still didn't work for me. Don't worry, I appreciate your  help, if we can't solve it, I'll keep trying whatever it is I can think of, and keep searching. I honestly appreciate you taking the time helping me out this far :)